# Subset data by month in R

Tags: r, time-series, aggregation

I am working with a time series of meteorological data and want to extract just the summer months. The data frame looks like this:

```
FECHA;H_SOLAR;DIR_M;DIR_S;VEL_M;VEL_S;VEL_X;U;V;TEMP_M;HR;BAT;PRECIP;RAD;UVA;UVB;FOG;GRID;
00/01/01;23:50:00;203.5;6.6;2.0;0.5;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;6.0;-99.9;9.0;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9
00/01/02;23:50:00;235.5;7.5;1.8;0.5;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;6.1;-99.9;8.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9
00/01/03;23:50:00;217.4;6.1;1.4;0.5;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;7.0;-99.9;8.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9
00/01/04;23:50:00;202.5;8.6;1.8;0.5;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;6.4;-99.9;8.8;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9
00/01/05;23:50:00;198.5;7.1;1.8;0.5;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;5.4;-99.9;8.8;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9;-99.9
```

I have found some examples of time subsetting in R but only between an starting and end date. What I want is to extract all data from a month for all years to create a new data frame to work with.  I can create a zoo time series from the data but how do I subset? zoo aggregate?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `xts::.indexmon`.  Creating an xts object is similar to creating a zoo object.  Assuming `xData` is your xts object, something like `xData[.indexmon(xData) %in% c(5,6,7)]` should do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use the `cycle()` function which gives the position in the cycle of each observation. For example:

```
gnp <- ts(cumsum(1 + round(rnorm(100), 2)),
          start = c(1954, 7), frequency = 12)

> cycle(gnp)
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1954                           7   8   9  10  11  12
1955   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
1956   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
..............
```

Then to subset a particular month, use the index of that month:

```
#Get all data from July
subset(gnp, cycle(gnp) == 7)
```

I should note that this returns a numeric vector, which may or may not be an issue for you depending on what you want to do from there. I'm curious to see other solutions as well.

Comment: Dear Chase, I've tried your sugggestion but get stuck on the first point. The ts(cumsum....) command does not give that integer numbers for each month. Later I will post the results as an answer to the question so you can see, the system makes me wait some hours to answer my own questions. Thanks.

Comment: is your data a `ts` object, or some other object? In order for cycle to work, your object needs to be a `ts` object and to have a `frequency` component associated with it. It isn't clear to me what your data above represents. Can you update your question with the results of `dput(yourData)`?

Comment: As your answer was the first one, Chase. I can't just start your suggestion. Take a look at the result of ts(cumsum....) It shows such a different result I can't understand

`gnp <- ts(cumsum(1 + round(rnorm(100), 2)),start = c(1954, 7), frequency = 12) `

This gives

**        Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep    Oct
1954                                            -1.55   0.44   1.28   0.32
1955   3.61   4.65   4.40   4.89   5.11   5.93   7.48   7.83   9.53  10.87
1956  15.45  16.22  17.43  20.89  22.89  25.45  26 **
not the integer numbers from your example, why??

Comment: @pacomet - ok, i clearly failed at my example. Above, `gnp` is an arbitrary example of a time series object (actually it comes from the help page for `?ts`). When making that time series object, we define a start year and month (1954 and month == 7), and then also specify that the number of observations per unit of time is 12 (monthly data). That time series object now has some "meta-data" associated with it, including the position of each observation which can be accessed by `cycle()`. Since that information is directly linked to the ts object itself, we can use it for subsetting / indexing

Comment: purposes. This is fundamentally the same concept as @Joshua showed you using xts which defined an index for your time series object. For an illustrative example, try running `
cbind(gnp, cycle(gnp), time(gnp))` in your console and viewing what is returned. As a note for future questions - the answers you get will be much more on target if you provide the exact structure of your data with `dput()`, as the answers will be different depending on the structure of your data, i.e. is it a data.frame? xts object? ts object? matrix? list? vector?

Comment: Hi, I made dput(data) but forgot to post it. You can see at [link](http://ubuntuone.com/p/14OE/). I understood your answer, the only problem was to reproduce gnp, I didn't get the same results and this was my mistake at reproducing. I'll try your last suggestion, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the months out your day/month/year column to a new column called 'month' using `substring()` e.g.,

```
mydata$month <- as.numeric( substring( mydata$dayMonthYear, first = 4, last = 5) )
```

This should create a column that just contains the months.

then subset based on the values of `$month`

```
summer.months <- subset(mydata, month > 5 & month < 9)
```

or

```
summer.months <- subset(mydata, month %in% c(5:9) )
```

Comment: Does this work with zoo objects? I can't seem to make this work for a "regular" ts object.

Comment: I'm not familiar with zoo objects to say. As a kludge could you coerce the day/month/year column to text?

Comment: Dear Chris, I can't figure out exactly the way to use grep. I've googled for grep syntax but get some errors and then I do not only grep month 05 but also day 05. Could you please post a detailed example. I'll add a new answer with the results I'm getting but I have to wait some hours as previously said in response to Chase.

Comment: @Pacomet - you can update your question with additional details, there shouldn't be any time restriction on that.

Comment: done, `substring()` actually might work better here than `grep()`. Your error with `grep()` might be because you were too specific. I'm guessing you were passing `05` in the search string, instead of `[[numeric]]`, and not limiting the string to what was between the backslashes. `substring()` gets around that.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your help. Let me write the three solutions working for me.

The first one is the answer form Joshua Ulrich:

Read the data, create an xts object and use indexmon

```
data=read.csv("peira.dat",sep=";",header=T,na.strings="-99.9")
dia=as.Date(data[,1],"%y/%m/%d")
xdata=xts(data[,c("PRECIP")],dia)
mdat=xdata[.indexmon(xdata) %in% c(5,6,7)]
```

Here is a plot of mdat [image]

The second solution came from the spanish R mailing list and uses lubridate package:

```
library(lubridate)

data=read.csv("peira.dat",sep=";",header=T,na.strings="-99.9")

f.dat<-parse_date(data$FECHA, c("%y", "%m", "%d"), seps="/")
data$m.dat<-month(f.dat, label=F, abbr=F)
dat.gd<-data[data$m.dat>5 & data$m.dat<9,]
dia=as.Date(dat.gd[,1],"%y/%m/%d")
dataz=zoo(dat.gd[,c("PRECIP")],dia)
```

The plot of dataz:
[image]

And the last one also from the spanish mailing list it uses POSIXct to take into account both date and time

```
tt=as.POSIXct(paste(data$FECHA,data$H_SOLAR), format="%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") 

datZoo <- zoo(data[,-c(1,2)], tt)

month <- function (x) as.numeric(format(x, "%m"))
veranoIdx <- which(month(tt) %in% 6:8)
veranoZoo <- datZoo[veranoIdx]
veranoZoo
```

Answer (score 1):

I just struggled with this for a while. Here's my simple solution using `lubridate`:

```
require('lubridate')
t <- xts( 1:24, seq.Date(from=as.Date('2011-01-01'), by='month', length.out=24 )
octobers <- t[ month(index(t)) == 10 ] # select out all octobers
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be very simple solutions. I would use a combination of the **zoo** and **seas** packages to aggregate by season, looking something like this:

```
library(zoo); library(seas)

seasTS <- aggregate(dataTS, mkseas(x=time(dataTS),width="DJF"), sum)
```

I'll have my coffee with a little syntactic sugar, please.